# Read last 5 lines of .txt file and display results in C# console app

Tags: c#, oop, console, instance, readfile

Background:

I'd like to develop my C# skills, and as a result have created an application which simulates a petrol station. Every 2 seconds, the app creates a new vehicle and assigns it to one of 9 pumps on a forecourt (whichever the next available one is). Once the vehicle has been refuelled after x amount of seconds, it leaves the pump and frees it so it can be used again. I've used Console.Clear() to redraw the forecourt design every time a vehicle enters or leaves the petrol station to give the impression of a dynamic app. As the vehicle leaves the petrol station, I want to record the type of vehicle, the number of litres of fuel dispensed and which pump it was serviced as to keep a sort of log of each transaction.

What I have done:

In this class, I've created a log which records the type of vehicle, the pump number at which it was serviced and how many litres of fuel were dispensed to that particular vehicle and writes this in a single line to a .txt file. I've then read from the .txt file and printed every line in the log.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace PetrolStationManagement
{
    class TransactionLog
    {
        public static Vehicle currentVehicle = null;

        public static void LogVehicle(Vehicle v, Pump p)
        {
            currentVehicle = v;
            Data.pumpNum = p;

            try
            {
                // passes filepath and filename to streamWriter constructor
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("G:\\PetrolStation\\TransactionLog.txt", true, Encoding.ASCII);

                // writes transaction details to file
                sw.WriteLine("{0}.\tVehicle Type: {1}\tPump No. : {2}\tLitres Dispensed to Vehicle: {3}\n", v.carID, v.vehicleType, p.pumpNum, Pump.litresDispensedToVehicle);

                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void ShowTransactions(Vehicle v, Pump p)
        {
            currentVehicle = v;
            Data.pumpNum = p;

            // shows details of all the transactions made
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("G:\\PetrolStation\\TransactionLog.txt")) // passes the filepath and filename to streamReader constructor
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) // read and display lines from file to console until end of file
                    {
                        // write line to console
                        Console.WriteLine(line);

                        // read next line
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is instead read from the .txt file and display the last 5 transactions on the console for the user to see, as otherwise the list will become excessively long - and the user won't be able to see the forecourt at the top which shows which pumps are available and which are in use.

I'm still relatively new to programming in general and I'm struggling to figure out how this could be done.

EDIT
I'm not too bothered about the encoding, as my main issue is not being sure how to read the last n lines of a file and displaying them to the console!!

Comment: Code that works for UTF-8 should work fine on ASCII, so long as it really is ASCII and not CP-1252 or something.

Answer (score 1):

> Most answer how to read the last n files if the text uses variable length coding such as UTF8. How would you go about doing this using fixed length encoding such as ASCII?? I'm still relatively new to programming in general and I'm struggling to figure out how this could be done!

The key is here is that your code shouldn't worry about the encoding. You can  just read lines and operate on them.

When you are reading a file, you should read the file in the correct encoding. [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding?view=netcore-2.1#System_IO_StreamReader_CurrentEncoding), for example, will identify the encoding in the file and use it automatically.

When you use `StreamReader`, it will give you a C# `string`. `string` objects always use a particular encoding (`UTF-16`). So you just need to operate on the UTF-16 string and not worry about whether the original file encoding was UTF-8, ASCII or UTF-32.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read (Reader.ReadLine()) the whole file into an array or list and then display the last entries of the array or list. In Textfiles i don't know any mechanics to access data specific.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() // or var lst = new List<string>();
while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
    lst.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}

for(int i = List.Count - 5; i < List.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(lst[i]);
}
```